# ¿Por qué no puedo salir del bucle "While" si uso la sentencia "Break"?

Tags: javascript

Es un pequeño programa, el problema viene cuando compruebo campos.

Por medio de un `prompt()` ingreso un valor numérico.

Condiciono que si al cancelar el `prompt()` me muestre un mensaje; hasta ahí todo bien. El problema es cuando en el `prompt()` ingresan texto.

Hay un bucle `while()` que dice que si es texto vuelve a pedir solo valores numéricos. Y dentro metro un `if()` que igual al cancelar el `prompt()` debería de darme un mensaje y salir del bucle con la sentencia `break` pero no lo hace.

¿Alguien podría orientarme por favor?

Dejo mi código.

```js
'use strict'
    
    // 2. Pide una nota (número). Muestra la calificación según la nota:
    
    var nota = prompt("ingresa tu edad");
    
    // Comprobamos si le dan en cancelar
    if (nota === null){
     alert("No ingresaste tu edad, Gracias");
    }
    
    // Mientras la nota sea un texto o esta vacio pedir un número hasta que este lleno el campo
    while (isNaN(nota) || nota == ""){
     nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa solo números"));
     if (nota === null) {
      alert("No ingresaste tu edad, Gracias");
      break;
     }
    }
```

**Actualizacion:**

Encontre el error. Resulta que el prompt que se encuentra en el bucle le aplica un parseInt. Se lo quite y funciono.

```
'use strict'

// 2. Pide una nota (número). Muestra la calificación según la nota:

var nota = prompt("ingresa tu edad");

// Comprobamos si le dan en cancelar
if (nota === null){
    alert("No ingresaste tu edad, Gracias");
}

// Mientras la nota sea un texto o esta vacio pedir un número hasta que este lleno el campo
while (isNaN(nota) || nota == "" || /\s/.test(nota)){
    var nota = prompt("Ingresa solo números");
    if (nota === null) {
        alert("No ingresaste tu edad, Gracias");
        break;
    }
}
```

Gracias a todos por su ayuda

Comment: Acabo de probar tu programa y funciona perfectamente, cuando le das a cancelar muestra un mensaje y cierra, rectifico, llevas razón, al entrar en el while se rompe

Comment: En el primer "cancel" del prompt si funciona.
Pero si meto un texto, luego me pide ingresar un número y le doy en cancelar ahi es cuando queda en bucle, aunque haya puesto una condicion con un break

Comment: Una cosa es que sea nulo el contenido y otra, que esté vacía la variable. Sospecho que crees que no respeta el break, pero puede estar pasando que nunca llega allí por esto que te comento.

Answer (score 0):

Con la función `is_null()` funciona bien, aunque entre en el while y se pulse cancelar, el programa se acaba

```js
    var nota = prompt("ingresa tu edad");
    
    // Comprobamos si le dan en cancelar
    if (nota === null){
     alert("No ingresaste tu edad, Gracias");
    }
    
    // Mientras la nota sea un texto o esta vacio pedir un número hasta que este lleno el campo
    while (isNaN(nota) || nota == ""){
     nota = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa solo números"));
     if (is_null(nota)) {
      alert("No ingresaste tu edad, Gracias");
      break;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Efectivamente con la función acaba el programa pero no me muestra el alert